# hadoop command works only when run with sudo

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop on mac Mojave, using brew install hadoop. When I run hadoop or hdfs command, it returns nothing.

For eg. If I run "hdfs dfs -ls /" it returns nothing in the command line (not even error). But when I run "sudo hdfs dfs -ls /" it works fine.

Same happens with Pig as well. When I run "pig" it returns nothing. But when I run "sudo pig" it starts the grunt shell.

I have done chown -R   and chown -R   but it didn't help.

Terminal output of list of files under `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/`

```
Bhadreshs-MacBook-Pro:~ bhadresh$ ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/ 
total 24 
drwxr-xr-x  5   bhadresh admin 160      Sep 11 12:15 . 
drwxrwxr-x  17  bhadresh admin 544      Sep 11 11:48 .. 
-rw-r--r--@ 1   bhadresh admin 10244    Sep 11 12:02 .DS_Store 
drwxr-xr-x  12  bhadresh admin 384      Sep 11 12:02 3.1.2 
drwxr-xr-x  3   bhadresh admin 96       Sep 11 12:15 hdfs 
Bhadreshs-MacBook-Pro:~ bhadresh$
```

Comment: Add the ouput of `ls -la ` in the installation folder. And also mention the current user you are running your command with. Mainly it looks like a permission issue. The hdfs file should be given appropriate executable permission from the specific user.

Comment: Bhadreshs-MacBook-Pro:~ bhadresh$ ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   5 bhadresh  admin    160 Sep 11 12:15 .
drwxrwxr-x  17 bhadresh  admin    544 Sep 11 11:48 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 bhadresh  admin  10244 Sep 11 12:02 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  12 bhadresh  admin    384 Sep 11 12:02 3.1.2
drwxr-xr-x   3 bhadresh  admin     96 Sep 11 12:15 hdfs
Bhadreshs-MacBook-Pro:~ bhadresh$